# SQL query to get the same set of results

Tags: sql, join

This should be a simple one, but say I have a table with data like this:

```
|    ID    |    Date      |    Value   |
|     1    | 01/01/2013   |      40    |
|     2    | 03/01/2013   |      20    |
|     3    | 10/01/2013   |      30    |
|     4    | 14/02/2013   |      60    |
|     5    | 15/03/2013   |      10    |
|     6    | 27/03/2013   |      70    |
|     7    | 01/04/2013   |      60    |
|     8    | 01/06/2013   |      20    |
```

What I want is the sum of values per week of the year, showing ALL weeks.. (for use in an excel graph)
What my query gives me, is only the weeks that are actually in the database.

Comment: so where is the query that does the magic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With SQL you cannot return rows that don't exist in some table. To get the effect you want you could create a table called `WeeksInYear` with only one field `WeekNumber` that is an `Int`.  Populate the table with all the week numbers.  Then `JOIN` that table to this one.

The query would then look something like the following:

```
SELECT w.WeekNumber, SUM(m.Value) 
FROM MyTable as m
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN WeeksInYear AS w 
  ON DATEPART(wk, m.date) = w.WeekNumber
GROUP BY w.WeekNumber
```

The missing weeks will not have any data in MyTable and show a 0.

Comment: The missing weeks will return `NULL` , not 0. But this approach is the correct one

Comment: OK.. hoped that there was some kind of trick. but this will do. Thanks!